# Microsoft sql trigger update multiple lines

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a two tables, a Customers and a Sales table. 
I am trying to create a trigger to update the amount of sales in the customer table when the Sales table is updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER salesUPDATE
ON SALES
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Customers
SET salesAmount = Sales.Amount
GO
```

But I get that sales does not exist. Should I be using a join? 
Will this trigger update all columns or do I need to specify which column to update?

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think is Yes, No, Yes

Comment: Also, as a general rule you do *not* want to do this kind of pre-aggregation in SQL databases.  Instead, you should create queries and or Views that do the roll-ups "on-demand".

Comment: You say `when the Sales table is updated`, but your trigger is `AFTER INSERT` maybe you need `AFTER UPDATE`

Comment: btw what is your rdbms? triggers sintaxis change between db.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ah, right. I was thinking rows, not columns.  It will update all rows (incorrectly) so the OP needs to specify which rows to update.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I would assume that AFTER INSERT is correct if OP wants to pre aggregate count of sales.  Update wouldn't change a count but insert and delete would.  where as if summing total $'s or something then update, insert, and delete would affect

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER salesUpdate ON SALES
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN

    ;WITH cteAffectedCustomers AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId
       FROM
          inserted

       UNION 

       SELECT DISTINCT CustomerId
       FROM
          deleted
    )

    , cteAggregations AS (
       SELECT
          ca.CustomerId
          ,SUM(ISNULL(s.Amount,0)) as SalesAmount
          ,COUNT(s.SalesId) as NumOfSales
       FROM
          cteAffectedCustomers ca
          INNER JOIN Customers c
          ON ca.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
          LEFT JOIN Sales s
          ON ca.CustomerId = s.CustomerId
       GROUP BY
          ca.CustomerId
    )

    UPDATE c
       SET SalesAmount = ca.SalesAmount
          ,NumOfSales = ca.NumOfSales
    FROM
       Customers c
       INNER JOIN cteAggregations ca
       ON c.CustomerId = ca.CustomerId

END
```

Here is an example of the type of logic you would need to create to maintain a pre-agregated value.  If you want to `SUM` an `Amount` in the `Sales` table you will need an `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE`. Then you would need to:

- determine all of the affected customers So you don't update the entire customer table
- do the aggregation
- update with an inner join to the aggregated data

A note about triggers, they are a set based operation NOT a scalar.  That means they fire once for x# of rows NOT x# of times for x# of rows.  So you have to account for multiple records during updates and do joins just like would outside of a trigger when updating one table with another.

This has a performance impact to write operations but does expedite your reads, however if you are not in an extremely extremely high read volume operation you would do better to use a view/query and optimize your indexes.  There is less likely hood of the synchronization of the aggregate data getting messed up.  If you do go the trigger route I suggest you also have a SQL job set up on some reasonable increment (nightly) that checks and rectifies any inconsistencies that may occur.

Answer (score 1):

Use magic table **inserted**

```
CREATE TRIGGER salesUPDATE
ON SALES
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  Declare @Amount varchar(50) = (Select top 1 Amount from inserted)
  UPDATE Customers
  SET salesAmount = @Amount
END
GO
```

**Note : top 1 for insertion of multiple records**

Answer (score -1):

Use the `inserted` table name which contains the new value:

```
CREATE TRIGGER salesUPDATE
ON SALES
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Customers
SET salesAmount = inserted.Amount
GO
```

Comment: NOTE: will not work correctly if more than one row at a time is inserted into `Sales`. (well, depending on the DBMS)